# Do split air conditioners like this also ventilate the room?

Tags: air-conditioning, appliances

I previously had read some articles online that said air conditioners like this don't do ventilation. The air inside the room keeps entering the indoor unit and cold air is blown into the room again and it keeps going on.

But recently, I had an argument with my electrician. He said you must close every smallest gap in the room to block outside air/atmosphere. Now I can understand the purpose of it, like it will reduce my electricity bill and room will maintain coolness.

But he gave another reason. When I said I don't want to close everything in the room except the door *(I tend to keep a small window open so there's still room for fresh air, because I feel when the room is completely closed, CO2 from breathing will increase in the room)* so there's some scope for ventilation (indirectly). He said are you mad. Split ACs themselves do ventilation. The outdoor unit on your roof helps do ventilation, so the air in your room is always fresh and cool. It moves the so called CO2 and hot and bad air from the room to the outer atmosphere.

So when this argument continued, I doubted myself and what I had read previously. I Googled again and saw no conclusive evidence that says a split AC does ventilation.

So I'm looking for a more authentic reference/answer which describes whether or not the split AC does ventilation.

Here are two examples of type of AC I'm concerned about:
[One](https://www.amazon.in/LG-Convertible-Anti-Virus-protection-MS-Q18PNXA/dp/B08WC9TZD6/ref=sr_1_2?crid=X240VVX7S2D1&dchild=1&keywords=split%20ac%201.5&qid=1623041209&sprefix=split%20ac%201.5%2Caps%2C307&sr=8-2) and [Two](https://www.amazon.in/Daikin-Inverter-Split-Copper-ATKL50TV/dp/B07HFK4JQP/ref=sxin_9?crid=X240VVX7S2D1&cv_ct_cx=split%20ac%201.5&dchild=1&keywords=split%20ac%201.5&pd_rd_i=B07HFK4JQP&pd_rd_r=ddf25e28-4651-464b-89cd-756f0f063f4f&pd_rd_w=czaGH&pd_rd_wg=l3tHN&pf_rd_p=40928eeb-7c20-4b50-af41-6cbace8168bd&pf_rd_r=W6QWN42J8T5MT4EM4RXY&qid=1623041209&sprefix=split%20ac%201.5%2Caps%2C307&sr=1-1-cda8f74c-98c1-454e-9da1-c6c00bc7b28b).

Comment: Look into an "energy recovery ventilator" or "heat recovery ventilator" (ERV or HRV) if you want ventilation with maximum conservation of energy (far better than an open window with a heat pump running, whether to heat or cool.)

Comment: You have two different arguments here.   A split A/C does not provide fresh air.  You SHOULD minimize open windows and doors for the A/C to work efficiently.   But you don't have to do that.  You can open a window a crack to get fresh air, and if the A/C is able to keep the room at a temperature you like and you don't mind the added cost, you should be happy.   You will not suffocate by closing doors and windows to a room cooled this way, unless it is a small room, you enter it with a lot of people, seal all the cracks with tape and stay in it for hours or days. So don't do that.

Comment: The key element is that it will take _days_ for the CO2 to build up enough to cause you any issues. Even tightly sealed newly built construction just isn't sealed that well.

Comment: @FreeMan my room has tiny and easily noticeable spaces with door and windows. I mean they aren't completely sealed at all. Even dust can enter my room easily if there's a storm. But my mom says you'll suffocate yourself if you keep door closed. I never felt suffocation at all though.

Comment: Love your mom, but know that she's wrong in this case.

Comment: @FreeMan CO2 can easily build up to headache-inducing levels overnight in a closed room.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Obviously not.

First hit on Google, when asking "does a split airconditioner provide fresh air"

> Though in split system air conditioners design, commonly heat pumps, part of your system is located outside your home, it does not take in outside air.

https://www.delcohvac.com/blog/do-air-conditioners-take-in-outside-air/

## Split Airconditioner

Have a look at how a split AC is installed:

[image]

There is an exchange of "heat" through the refrigerant tubing (hot liquid goes out, comes back cold), but no air is exchanged. The inside unit it placed against a wall and it has no air access to the outside. In fact this is a practical and aesthetic selling feature: it does not require a window.

### Filters in a split AC

The filter in the outside and inside units are not to filter fresh air entering the house, obviously, but to keep the air exchanger clean so that they work more efficiently. Dust, dirt and grim (dust & fat) that covers the metal exchanger forms an insulating layer like a coat blanket, and reduces the heat exchange necessary to provide cooling.

## Window air conditioner with outside-air intake

A window air conditioner is different: because it has a access to the outside, it can pull-in or push-out a small amount of air while running, thus directly exchanging the air in the room it cools.

Heres's a diagram and it shows a "damper". It is a flap at a small  opening that connects inside with outside. When the AC runs, the fans create a small pressure difference at the flap that then opens allowing entry of outside air:

[image]

## Exchanging Air

If you wish to provide fresh air into the living space, you need a separate ventilation system for that. You can theoretically leave a door open, or run a fan to circulate air in & out of a gap in the window, but these will cost a lot in lost cooling (summer) or lost heating (winter).

An ERV or HRV is different from a simple crack in the door or a fan at the window because the air that is drawn in is cooled using the "coolness" of the air that is sent out. You need power to run the fans, but the cooling comes for free.

### ERV

In a hot an humid climate you would use a ERV instead. An "Energy Recovery Ventilator" will exchange inside air for outside air, replacing the stale air with (hopefully) more fresh outside air, and it will help keep the humidity inside low even if the hot but fresh outside air is humid.

### HRV

If humidity is not a concern you can use an HRV (Heat Recovery Ventilator), which is practically the same but without the moisture exchange.

Have a look:

[image]

Stale inside air goes out and better outside air is pulled in.

### Heat Exchanger

That cubic-shaped block in the middle brings the two flows of close to each other, flowing over aluminium plates, to allow the temperature to equalize through the metal: the fresh outside air is cooled a bit by the air sent out, so that the air conditioner does not have to cool it as much as when your draw-in hot air from the outside.

[image]

Further reading in ERV vs HRV:

https://www.ecohome.net/guides/2276/choosing-between-an-hrv-and-an-erv/

Image credits:

https://www.pinterest.ca/pin/469781804853382012/

https://www.pvhvac.com/blog/erv-or-ventilating-dehumidifier-which-is-better-for-georgia-homes

https://www.engineeredair.com/index.php/our_products/category/energy-recovery-and-iaq-products

https://www.brighthubengineering.com/hvac/55429-how-to-install-window-air-conditioner/

Comment: The split air is strictly internal air recirculation. There's no air intake at all. The split unit simply passes cold gas into the room to cool the air inside, and the giant fan on the outside unit is to cool the refrigerant. No new air is drawn into the house from this. Coming out of the split air would be only two pipes; one for the cold refrigerant, and one for the condensation. There are no air pipes at all.

Comment: That guy obviously haven't even cleaned a split-air conditioner. If you take off the filter and take it apart for a thorough cleaning, there's no duct of any kind.

Comment: @Nelson I just know how to clean the outer filter. Duct means?

Comment: A "duct" in this context is a tube for carrying air.

Comment: @Vikas, you are getting some good answers in the comments here and under your question, so keep following up until you have what you need to make an informed decision. If there is terminology from others like Nelson, Ecnerwal, jay613 or myself that you don't understand, it's sometimes faster and more effective (but not necessary on this DIY site) if you just google it, and then come back with a follow-up.

Answer (score 2):

You have already accepted an answer but there are 2 types of split systems.

Mini split these are sealed systems and do not bring in makeup air. They work exactly as you thought.

a large central air split system may have a make up air port (some do and some do not) but if they do it’s on the return duct so the air handler is pulling fresh air in while running.

You are also correct that Co2 can accumulate in modern housing that is air sealed this can lead to headaches as one of the leading identified health issues. each breath you exhale approximately 5% Co2 , having a little fresh air to me is a must.

Answer (score 0):

Daikin ururu sarara is a traditional hi wall split system that does incorporate a fresh air inlet system in it. I've installed them. You do pay for the privilege.

Comment: Yeah looks like they cost a lot. Not available here though.